# QOpenGLWidget: The viewport is not updated when adding objects dynamically

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I can't solve this. Either QOpenGLWidget is broken or I'm doing something wrong.
I'm trying to add entities on screen dynamically. I add them on a stack and draw them in the paintGL() method.

```
void C_OpenGL::addEntity(float x, float y, float z)
{
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices = {
        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),

        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),

        Vertex(-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),

        Vertex(0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),

        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),

        Vertex(-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f)
    };

    ent->addComponent<C_MeshRenderer>(vertices);
    entities.push_back(ent);

    update();
}
```

In the paintGL() method I draw entities like so

```
void paintGL()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++)
    {
        entities[i]->update();
        entities[i]->draw(renderer);
    }
}
```

I have connected the update() method to a timer in the C_OpenGL constructor.
When I try to place entities nothing is shown. It seems like the screen is not updated. When inherit from QGLWidget class however everything works fine.